# MDM model update deployment

Tags: deployment, mdm, mds

I've recently started an internship in an IT company and have been given a project to work on that involves making changes to a model on their MDM server. I've made these changes on the dev server and am now ready to deploy to production.

I've done some research on deployment and found out that I can only perform a model update deployment if the initial deployment type was clone, but unfortunately the initial deployment type was new.

Would anyone have any advice as to what would be the best and safest way to perform the update?

Is it possible to create a model deployment package from the production server, delete the model and deploy the package as a clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use deploy clone when deploying model, if you  use deploy new then the MUID will not be changed and next time when you will update your model it will say that there is already a model with same MUID, in this case you should use Deploy clone rather than deploy new.
Now delete your model and create new model with deploy clone option.